# data file is not including the last line in python

Tags: python

When I run the code it dumps the `'Values.dat'` file but after that when I try to load these data into a variable so that I can proceed into further calculation....the variable `c` is loading all data but the the last line.

```
fs=glob.glob('*all_strain_rate_data_files/srate*.txt')
for fil in fs:
    sr=float(fil.split('srate')[1].split('.txt')[0])
    xy=loadtxt(fil)
    y=xy[:,1]
    avg=mean(y)
    n_f= open('Values.dat' , 'a')
    n_f.writelines(str(sr)+'\t'+str(avg)+'\n')
    n_f.close

c = loadtxt('Values.dat')
print c
```

The `.dat` file has the following data

```
0.001   -0.000476901658291
0.005   -0.000459584857803
0.01    -0.000455371401619
0.02    -0.000454457184105
0.03    -0.000363427058283
0.04    -0.000425998443982
0.05    -0.000479518449808
0.06    -0.00044039265987
0.07    -0.000428992925364
0.08    -0.000479521006314
0.09    -0.000346052124686
0.5 -0.000419424003512


And the print of c ........gives
[[ 0.001      -0.0004769 ]
 [ 0.005      -0.00045958]
 [ 0.01       -0.00045537]
 [ 0.02       -0.00045446]
 [ 0.03       -0.00036343]
 [ 0.04       -0.000426  ]
 [ 0.05       -0.00047952]
 [ 0.06       -0.00044039]
 [ 0.07       -0.00042899]
 [ 0.08       -0.00047952]
 [ 0.09       -0.00034605]
```

N.B : if I do the following in another python script it it loads the last line.

```
c = loadtxt('Values.dat')
print c
```

So if it can work in separate script then why it is not reading the last line in same script ?

Comment: You overdid it with the indentation a bit.

Comment: The C tag is not for programs that use the variable name `c`.

Answer (score 1):

You are unnecessarily opening and closing the file in the loop. You should open it out of the loop, and then close it once you are done:

```
fs=glob.glob('*all_strain_rate_data_files/srate*.txt') 
n_f= open('Values.dat' , 'a')

for fil in fs:
    sr=float(fil.split('srate')[1].split('.txt')[0])
    xy=loadtxt(fil)
    y=xy[:,1]
    avg=mean(y)        
    n_f.writelines(str(sr)+'\t'+str(avg)+'\n')

n_f.close    
c = loadtxt('Values.dat') print c
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but still its having the same problem. Can't load the last line of datafile Values.dat

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out.....why last line of the datafile is not loaded. @pug